# Удаление ключ-значение по фильтру

Tags: python, словари, dict

Необходимо удалить ключ значение из словаря:

Вот код:

```
leads = [{'id': 'value2', 'num': 523541, 'status_id': 321, 'group_id': 721},{'id': 'value1', 'num': 123456, 'status_id': 123, 'group_id': 127}]

def removekey(d, key): 
    r = dict.copy(d) 
    del r[key]
    return r 

for i, elem in enumerate(leads):
    for key in leads[i]:
        if key != 'id':
            test = removekey(leads[i], key)
```

То есть по сути хочу удалить все ключ-значение кроме ключа 'id'. 
Ошибок нет, но весь словарь остается и не удаляется, хотя в removekey заходит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не удаляет?

Comment: У меня ваш код вызывает ошибку: `KeyError: 0` и это логично, т.к. в `leads[i]` передается индекс ключа, а не сам ключ

Comment: Если надо удалить все, кроме одного значения, не проще ли просто забрать это значение?

Comment: Исправил, там лист со словарями. Прошу прощения не правильно изначально написал.

Comment: @mkkik там много ключей и нужно оставить несколько.

Comment: Тем более, лучше сформировать новый словарь по набору необходимых ключей.

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления значений из словаря используйте метод [dict.pop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop).

Пример:

```
leads = [{'id': 'value2', 'num': 523541, 'status_id': 321, 'group_id': 721},{'id': 'value1', 'num': 123456, 'status_id': 123, 'group_id': 127}]

for d in leads:
    for key in list(d.keys()):
        if key != 'id':
            d.pop(key)

print(leads)
# [{'id': 'value2'}, {'id': 'value1'}]
```

Для нескольких ключей проверка была бы например такая:

```
if key not in ('id', 'num'):
```

Comment: Исправил: изначально дан лист со словарями. И в этих словарях нужно удалить не нужные ключ-значение

Comment: там много ключей и нужно оставить несколько

Comment: @danilfg, это была важная деталь :) Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вы в функции `removekey` делаете копию словаря, из нее удаляете ключ. Естественно, исходный словарь не изменится. Можно просто менять исходный словарь без создания копии:

```
leads = [{'id': 'value2', 'num': 523541, 'status_id': 321, 'group_id': 721},{'id': 'value1', 'num': 123456, 'status_id': 123, 'group_id': 127}]

for i, elem in enumerate(leads):
    # Набор ключей собирается в список,
    # чтобы избежать исключения "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"
    for key in list(elem):
        if key != 'id':
            del elem[key]

print(leads)
```

Другой вариант решения - через генератор словаря (dict comprehension):

```
leads = [{'id': 'value2', 'num': 523541, 'status_id': 321, 'group_id': 721},{'id': 'value1', 'num': 123456, 'status_id': 123, 'group_id': 127}]

for i, elem in enumerate(leads):
    leads[i] = {key: value for key, value in elem.items() if key == 'id'}

print(leads)
```

Вообще, если нужно значение только по одному ключу, то внутренний цикл не нужен, можно просто брать значение по этому ключу, и записывать в новый словарь:

```
leads = [{'id': 'value2', 'num': 523541, 'status_id': 321, 'group_id': 721},{'id': 'value1', 'num': 123456, 'status_id': 123, 'group_id': 127}]

for i, elem in enumerate(leads):
    if 'id' in elem:
        leads[i] = dict(id=elem['id'])
    else:
        leads[i] = dict()  # Учитываем случай, когда данного ключа нет в словаре

print(leads)
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо!
Решение нашел:

```
leads = [{'id': 'value2', 'num': 523541, 'status_id': 321, 'group_id': 721},{'id': 'value1', 'num': 123456, 'status_id': 123, 'group_id': 127}]

test = copy.deepcopy(leads)
for i, elem in enumerate(leads):
    for key in leads[i]:
        if key != 'id':
            test[i].pop(key)
```

Comment: Зачем делать копию списка словарей?

Comment: Зачем `enumerate`?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения в одну строчку :)

```
leads = [{'id': 'value2', 'num': 523541, 'status_id': 321, 'group_id': 721},{'id': 'value1', 'num': 123456, 'status_id': 123, 'group_id': 127}]
leads = [dict(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'id', d.items())) for d in leads]
```

На выходе:

```
# [{'id': 'value2'}, {'id': 'value1'}]
```

Как вариант можно ещё вот так:

```
leads =[{k: v} for d in leads for k,v in d.items() if k == 'id']
```